# Model selection with dropout training neural network

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I've been studying neural networks for a bit and recently learned about the dropout training algorithm. There are excellent papers out there to understand how it works, including the ones from the authors.

So I built a neural network with dropout training (it was fairly easy) but I'm a bit confused about how to perform model selection. From what I understand, looks like dropout is a method to be used when training the final model obtained through model selection.

As for the test part, papers always talk about using the complete network with halved weights, but they do not mention how to use it in the training/validation part (at least the ones I read).

I was thinking about using the network without dropout for the model selection part. Say that makes me find that the net performs well with N neurons. Then, for the final training (the one I use to train the network for the test part) I use 2N neurons with dropout probability p=0.5. That assures me to have exactly N neurons active on average, thus using the network at the right capacity most of the time.

Is this a correct approach?

By the way, I'm aware of the fact that dropout might not be the best choice with small datasets. The project I'm working on has academic purposes, so it's not really needed that I use the best model for the data, as long as I stick with machine learning good practices.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, model selection and the training of a particular model are completely different issues. For model selection, you would usually need a data set that is completely independent of both training set used to build the model and test set used to estimate its performance. So if you're doing for example a cross-validation, you would need an inner cross-validation (to train the models and estimate the performance in general) and an outer cross-validation to do the model selection.

To see why, consider the following thought experiment (shamelessly stolen from [this paper](http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/abs/10.1162/EVCO_a_00069)). You have a model that makes a completely random prediction. It has a number of parameters that you can set, but have no effect. If you're trying different parameter settings long enough, you'll eventually get a model that has a better performance than all the others simply because you're sampling from a random distribution. If you're using the *same* data for all of these models, this is the model you will choose. If you have a *separate* test set, it will quickly tell you that there is no real effect because the performance of this parameter setting that achieves good results during the model-building phase is not better on the separate set.

Now, back to neural networks with dropout. You didn't refer to any particular paper; I'm assuming that you mean Srivastava et. al. "Dropout: A Simple Way to Prevent Neural Networks from Overfitting". I'm not an expert on the subject, but the method to me seems to be similar to what's used in random forests or bagging to mitigate the flaws an individual learner may exhibit by applying it repeatedly in slightly different contexts. If I understood the method correctly, essentially what you end up with is an average over several possible models, very similar to random forests.

This is a way to make an individual model better, but not for model selection. The dropout is a way of adjusting the learned weights for a single neural network model.

To do model selection on this, you would need to train and test neural networks with different parameters and then evaluate those on completely different sets of data, as described in the paper I've referenced above.

Comment: You're right about everything, I probably didn't explain myself well. I know how to use the data for training, validation and test (I also know about that experiment, although presented in a slightly different manner), it was just about how to apply the model to the validation part (yet I think I am not explaining myself well even with this sentence). But thanks for the resource, I'll read it and surely learn something new from it.